# Cross-Validation in apache-spark. How to create Parameter Grid?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, cross-validation

I am trying to set up a ParamGrid for using cross-validation later. But I could not find any explanation about the input arguments.

After creating a pipeline I am trying to create a parameter grid, but since I do not understand, which entries are expected I keep getting errors.

```
//creating my pipeline with indexer, oneHotEncoder, creating the feature vector and applying linear regression on it
val IndexedList = StringList.flatMap{ name =>

    val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol(name).setOutputCol(name + "Index")

    val encoder = new OneHotEncoderEstimator()
        .setInputCols(Array(name+ "Index"))
        .setOutputCols(Array(name + "vec"))

  Array(indexer,encoder)
  }

 val features = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("Modellvec", "KM", "Hubraum", "Fuelvec","Farbevec","Typevec","F1","F2","F3","F4","F5","F6","F7","F8")).setOutputCol("Features2")
  val linReg = new LinearRegression()//.setFeaturesCol(features2.getOutputCol).setLabelCol("Preis")

//creates the Array of stages
  val IndexedList3 = (IndexedList :+ features :+ linReg).toArray[PipelineStage]

  val pipeline2 = new Pipeline()

//This grid should be created in order to apply cross-validation
  val <b>pipeline_grid</b> = new ParamGridBuilder()
      .baseOn(pipeline2.stages -> IndexedList3)
      .addGrid(linReg.regParam, Array(10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75) ).build()
```

The first part works just fine when I run it separately.

The problem is, that I do not understand, how the Array in "addGrid" should look like(or how I should choose the values) and why it is a problem, that linReg.regParam is of type DoubleParam, since addGrid IS defined on this type.

In most examples I have seen, this Array appears out of nowhere. So could someone explain to me, where it comes from?

Comment: What are the specific errors you are getting? Could you please add the specific exception and error message.

Comment: I get the following type mismatch:

`Error:(76, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.ml.param.DoubleParam
 required: org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param[AnyVal]
Note: Double <: AnyVal (and org.apache.spark.ml.param.DoubleParam <: org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param[Double]), but class Param is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
      .addGrid(linReg.regParam, Array(10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75) ).build()`

Comment: Found this error, it was supposed to be Array(10.0,15.0.....)
But still, how do I have to choose those numbers?